# In Stripe How to Avoid a user making multiple callback with same session_id

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have a payment system using a stripes checkout session where a user pays and then is redirected to a success page where I make a call to my BE with the session Id and check the status & client_reference_id and then allot the credit. Now After this step, I want to avoid a scenario where the user uses the same session ID and gets more and more credits using the same session Id.

I thought expiring a session but it only works on `open`
status.

**Is there any way to avoid this?**

Comment: You would want to check for if credit has already been allotted before. One way would be to have your own database with the Checkout Session Id, and client_reference_id and a column which indicates if credit has already been allotted.

Comment: yes @alex saving the session id in the transaction table will work for me. I was just wondering why Stripe doesn't have any status which depicts -- payment is done and cannot be used again -- especially for use cases like a checkout.

Comment: For context, Stripe's Checkout Session Object does have a [status](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-status) parameter. A customer cannot make payment twice for the same Checkout Session Object so I don't quite understand why you're asking `why Stripe doesn't have any status which depicts -- payment is done and cannot be used again`. Also, completing payment on the Checkout Session doesn't directly relate to you having credited the user. For example, the customer might have completed payment, but your request to credit the user might have failed.